# I need to render a web page with the results of a MySQL query - is my code ok?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I want to design a web page that accepts an input, finds values in a particular column of a MySQL table that at least partially matches it, and then prints out all rows which match that column on an HTML page. Here's the cgi:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import mysql.connector
import cgi
import jinja2
import re
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

def main():
    templateLoad = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./templates")
    environs = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoad)
    template = environs.get_template('search_template.html')

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    acc = form.getfirst('accession')

    conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxxx',password = 'xxxxx',host = 'localhost',database = 'xxxxx')

    qry = "SELECT * from testis_sQTL WHERE gene_name LIKE '%s%'";

    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(qry, ('%'+acc+'%',))

    print(template.render(curs=curs, accs=acc))

    conn.close()
    curs.close()
```

The MySQL query `SELECT * from testis_sQTL WHERE gene_name LIKE '%s%'` works in MySQL, as in it returns rows that match the query in the `gene_name` column. When I run this script server-side (`./main.cgi`), I get no errors, but online, the website gives me a 500 error. I'm trying to at least get the script to properly pass onto the following template, which is why the `print(template.render(curs=curs, accs=acc))` is probably incorrect.

Here's the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          td {
            border: 1px solid rgb(80,80,80);
            padding: 3px;
          }
          table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Search Results
        </h1>
        <p>
            Your Query: {{curs}}
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Accession</td>
                <td>Gene Product</td>
            </tr>
        <!--{% for acc in accs %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ acc[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ acc[1] }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %} -->
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I commented out the part where the results are actually printed out because I just want the template to render without the results first. Also, I am just reusing this code from a previous assignment.

What do I do from here? I feel like I'm at a loss because the script, when run from commandline, doesn't give any errors, and when I try to access it online, I only get a generic sort of "Internal server error" message.

EDIT: Here's the generic "Internal Server Error" message. I also should note that I have not posted the code for the HTML submission form, because I'm assuming it works.

[image: Generic error]

EDIT: Here is my error message not as an image

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: post your  error message plz

Comment: post the error message from the web server /cgi log

Comment: I posted it. This is the error I get when I try to use the cgi online, I get no errors server-side. Also my class' server does not log errors for some reason; `cgitb` doesn't really work.

Comment: I've added `python` tags so you should get more views

Comment: you should change '%s%' to %s.BTW, don't post error message as image

Comment: @wl.GIG 10-4 got it

Comment: What server environment are you running in (Apache, IIS, etc)?

Comment: I don't know and I don't know how to find out